# Get last record from dependent table based on condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables in my rails application.

1. tasks
2. tasks_statuses

Below are the records

**tasks table**

`id      task_name   date
1       A           2019-03-30
2       B           2019-03-30
3       C           2019-03-30`

**task_statuses table**

`id task_id status_id 
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   1       3
4   2       1
5   1       4
6   2       2`


`Status Id and there meaning
1       Started
2       Running
3       Pause
4       Complete`

Now, 
if I search with status_id 2 (Running) in that case task_id 2 should be return
if I search with status_id 4 (Complete) in that case task_id 1 should be return

Can somebody helps how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `statuses` table?

Comment: How do your models named?

Comment: Yes, I have models as well as tables.

Comment: Get last running task can be done using `Task.joins(:task_statuses).where(status_id: 2).order(:id).last`. If you want just id of the task append `.id` to above expression.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve by

> tasks = tasks.joins(:task_statuses).where('task_statuses.status_id = ?
>   AND task_statuses.status_id = (SELECT max(status_id) from
>   task_statuses where task_statuses.task_id = tasks.id)',
>   params[:status_id])